# docker-compose.ymlにおける、初期コマンドのバックグラウンド実行

Tags: docker, docker-compose

お世話になっております。

docker-compose up -dを実行した際に、各コンテナの起動→シェルをバックグラウンド実行させたいと思っております。

docker-compose.ymlを下記のように作成しました。

```
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    image: test:latest
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    working_dir: /opt/test
    command: bash -c "./test.sh &"
```

しかし、docker-compose up -dを実行すると、コンテナがexitの状態で作成されます。
また、最終行の"./test.sh &"を"./test.sh"にすると、バックグラウンドで動いているようですが、コンテナ内でbashが起動しておらず、docker exec -it test bash で入らなければなりません。

docker-compose up -d コマンドだけで、コンテナ起動→bashによるシェルのバックグラウンド実行→デタッチまで行うためには、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のコードで再現と改善をしてみました。
意図されていることとあっているでしょうか。

コンテナをビルドします。

```
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04

COPY test.sh /opt/test/test.sh
$ cat test.sh
#! /bin/sh

echo running background! > /tmp/cmd.log
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  33.42MB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> 113a43faa138
Step 2/2 : COPY test.sh /opt/test/test.sh
 ---> 2bd8dc58d62d
Removing intermediate container 138e6b2c52ee
Successfully built 2bd8dc58d62d
Successfully tagged test:latest
$
```

ビルドしたコンテナを使って再現します。

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating compose_test_1 ... done
$ docker-compose ps
     Name              Command         State    Ports
-----------------------------------------------------
compose_test_1   bash -c ./test.sh &   Exit 0        
$
```

下記の通りcommandを修正します。

```
$ git diff --word-diff
diff --git a/docker-compose.yml b/docker-compose.yml
index fdfa503..a504ca6 100644
--- a/docker-compose.yml
+++ b/docker-compose.yml
@@ -5,4 +5,4 @@ services:
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    working_dir: /opt/test
    command: bash -c "./test.sh [-&"-]{+& tail -f /dev/null"+}
$
```

起動して確認します。

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Recreating compose_test_1 ... done
$ docker-compose ps
     Name                   Command               State   Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------
compose_test_1   bash -c ./test.sh & tail - ...   Up           
$ docker-compose exec test cat /tmp/cmd.log
running background!
$
```

docker attachしたいという事でしたので下記のように修正してみました。

```
$ cat test.sh
#! /bin/sh

while true
do
    date
    sleep 1
done
$
```

下記のように起動してdocker attachすることができます。

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting compose_test_1 ... done
$ docker attach compose_test_1 
Thu Jun 28 07:24:15 UTC 2018
Thu Jun 28 07:24:16 UTC 2018
Thu Jun 28 07:24:17 UTC 2018
Thu Jun 28 07:24:18 UTC 2018
Thu Jun 28 07:24:19 UTC 2018
Thu Jun 28 07:24:20 UTC 2018
[Ctrl]-[p][Ctrl]-[q]
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご提示いただいた内容だと、command: bash -c "./test.sh" としたときと同じ動作になると思います。説明が悪く申し訳ありませんが、docker-compose up -d をしたあとに、docker attach compose_test_1 とコマンドをうつと、アタッチできてbashが起動し、psコマンドでバックグラウンドでtest.shが動いていて欲しいのです。

Comment: test.shの処理にattachする必要があるという事でしたらバックグラウンドで実行するのではなくフォアグラウンドで実行する必要があると思います。バックグラウンドで実行させて、かつattachしたいというのはできないと思います。